# Paho MQTT client in Android that has to be accessed in multiple activities

Tags: java, android

I am having an app that has multiple activities and uses MQTT.

I am using the Paho client in Gradle dependencies as follows:

```
compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.3-SNAPSHOT'
```

I would be using username and password to connect to the broker and some activities would be using different user name and password.

Currently, I am handling the `connect`,`subscribe`and `publish` tasks in each activity as in the code that I will include below. As the activities get more and more I am having issues. Please suggest me how I can port the code to a service or singleton so that it can be reused and become efficient.

Here is one of the activities:

```
package net.kindows.chitchat;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.pixplicity.easyprefs.library.Prefs;

import net.kindows.SplashScreen;
import net.kindows.common.ApplicationLoader;
import net.kindows.common.utils;
import net.kindows.intlPhone.IntlPhoneInput;

import org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttAndroidClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttActionListener;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttDeliveryToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.IMqttToken;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttCallback;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget.crouton.Crouton;

import static net.kindows.common.ApplicationLoader._toast;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MqttCallback {

    private static final String TAG = "LoginActivity";
    private static final int REQUEST_SIGNUP = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_PAS_RESET = 1;

    private static final Integer LOGGED_OUT = 0;
    private static final Integer LOGGING_IN = 1;
    private static final Integer WAITING_FOR_SING_IN_ACK = 2;
    private static final Integer LOGGED_IN = 3;
    private static final Integer VERIFICATION_FAILED = 4;

    @Bind(R.id.input_password)
    EditText _passwordText;
    @Bind(R.id.btn_login)
    Button _loginButton;
    @Bind(R.id.link_signup)
    TextView _signupLink;

    @Bind(R.id.my_phone_input)
    IntlPhoneInput _phoneInputView;
    String sUserName = null;
    String sPassword = null;
    String sDestination = null;
    String sMessage = null;

    private Integer state;
    private Handler han = new Handler();
    private MqttConnectOptions connOpt;
    private ProgressDialog _progressDialog;
    /*
        MQTT mqtt = null;

        FutureConnection connection = null;*/
    private boolean isMinimized = false;
    private String clientId;
    private Handler loginAgain = new Handler();
    private Handler timeout;
    private MqttAndroidClient client;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        //connect();
        _loginButton.setEnabled(false);

        // _phoneInputView.setNumber(ApplicationLoader.getSim1number(LoginActivity.this));
        _phoneInputView.setOnValidityChange(new IntlPhoneInput.IntlPhoneInputListener() {
            @Override
            public void done(View view, boolean isValid) {
                if (isValid) {
                    _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else _loginButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
        _loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!ApplicationLoader.isConnected(LoginActivity.this, true)) {
                } else login();
            }
        });

        _signupLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Start the Signup activity
                Prefs.putInt(getString(R.string.key_reset_pass), 2);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignUpActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SIGNUP);
            }
        });
        state = LOGGED_OUT;
        connOpt = new MqttConnectOptions();
        connOpt.setCleanSession(true);
        connOpt.setKeepAliveInterval(30);
        connOpt.setCleanSession(true);

        clientId = ApplicationLoader.getClientId(LoginActivity.this);
        client = new MqttAndroidClient(this, "tcp://104.131.50.64:1883", clientId, MqttAndroidClient.Ack.AUTO_ACK);//this,"tcp://104.131.50.64:1883", "app1", null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        isMinimized = true;
        // super.onDestroy();
        try {

            client.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // client.unregisterResources();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Crouton.cancelAllCroutons();
        loginAgain.removeCallbacks(null);
        han.removeCallbacks(null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Do not go to splash screen if came from signup activity
        if (isMinimized && Prefs.getBoolean(getString(R.string.show_splash), true)) {
            isMinimized = false;
            han.removeCallbacks(null);
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SplashScreen.class));
            finish();
        }
        Prefs.putBoolean(getString(R.string.show_splash), true);
        if (utils.getLoginState_login()) {
            han.removeCallbacks(null);
            utils._startActivity(this, MainActivity.class);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (utils.getLoginState_login()) {
            han.removeCallbacks(null);
            utils._startActivity(this, MainActivity.class);
            finish();

        }

        ApplicationLoader.isConnected(this, true);

    }

    public void login() {
        Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.login));
        _toast(getString(R.string.logging_in), LoginActivity.this);

        try {
            client.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            client.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Disable login button for 5 secs
        final boolean lastLoginState = _loginButton.isEnabled();
        _loginButton.setEnabled(false);
        loginAgain.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                _loginButton.setEnabled(lastLoginState);
            }
        }, 5000);

        _progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this,
                R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
        // String phone = _phoneText.getText().toString();
        String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();
        String numb = _phoneInputView.getNumber().replace("+", "");
        connectMQTT(numb, password);
        _progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        _progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
        _progressDialog.show();

        han.postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {  // On complete call either onLoginSuccess or onLoginFailed
                        //onLoginSuccess();
                        onLoginFailed();
                        _progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, ApplicationLoader.timeOUT);
    }

    private void publish2MQQT(MqttAndroidClient client1, String topic, String msg) throws MqttException {
        if (client1 != null) {

            MqttMessage msg2 = new MqttMessage();
            msg2.setPayload(msg.getBytes());
            client1.publish(topic, msg2, this, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    // _sendErrorLog("on sucess of publish");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    // _sendErrorLog("on fail of publish e= " + exception.getMessage());
                    _progressDialog.dismiss();
                    _toast((exception != null ? exception.getMessage() : ""), LoginActivity.this);
                }
            });

            // Log.e("mqtt ", "published " + msg);
        }

    }

    private void _sendErrorLog(String s) {
        Log.e("LOG", s);
    }

    private void connectMQTT(final String user, final String pass) {
        Log.e("connectMQTT", "1");

        try {
            connOpt.setUserName(user);
            connOpt.setPassword(pass.toCharArray());
            _sendErrorLog("on connteing with " + user + "  " + pass);
            client.connect(connOpt, this, new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    _sendErrorLog("on success of connect");
                    try {
                        client.subscribe("astr/app/iremote/" + user.replace("+", ""), 0, this, new IMqttActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                                _sendErrorLog("on sucess of subscribe");

                                // TODO: Implement your own authentication logic here.
                                JsonObject msg = new JsonObject();
                                msg.addProperty("u", user);
                                msg.addProperty("P", pass);

                                sUserName = user;
                                sPassword = pass;
                                sDestination = "astr/admin/signin";
                                sMessage = msg.toString();
                                state = LOGGING_IN;
                                try {
                                    Log.e("register", "publishing signin message");
                                    if (client == null) {
                                        Log.e("register", "publishing register message client is null");

                                    }
                                    publish2MQQT(client, sDestination, sMessage);
                                    state = WAITING_FOR_SING_IN_ACK;
                                } catch (MqttException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Log.e("register", "got exception in publish " + e.toString());
                                    _progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    _toast(e.getMessage(), LoginActivity.this);

                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                                _sendErrorLog("on failure of subscribe  " + exception.getMessage());
                                _progressDialog.dismiss();
                                _toast((exception != null ? exception.getMessage() : ""), LoginActivity.this);

                            }
                        });
                        // client.subscribe("astr/app/iremote/" + _num_2b_verified.replace("+", ""));
                    } catch (MqttException | NullPointerException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    _sendErrorLog("on failure of connect" + exception.getMessage());
                    han.removeCallbacks(null);
                    try {
                        _progressDialog.dismiss();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    _toast((exception != null ? exception.getMessage() : ""), LoginActivity.this);

                }
            });
            client.setCallback(this);

        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("connectMQTT", "got exception  ::  " + e.toString());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
        Log.e("connection", "lost");
        //connectMQTT();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        try {
            client.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {

        String msgRecived = new String(mqttMessage.getPayload());
        /* Log.e("message arrived", "-------------------------------------------------");
        Log.e("message arrived", "| Topic:" + s);*/
        Log.e("message arrived", "| Message: " + msgRecived);
        /*Log.e("message arrived" , "-------------------------------------------------");*/

        if (state.equals(WAITING_FOR_SING_IN_ACK)) {

            han.removeCallbacks(null);
            JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
            JsonObject reply = (JsonObject) jp.parse(msgRecived);
            if (reply.get("s").getAsInt() == 200) {
                _toast(getString(R.string.logged_in), LoginActivity.this);
                _progressDialog.dismiss();
                _phoneInputView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                _passwordText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                _loginButton.setText(R.string.logged_in);
                _loginButton.setEnabled(true);
                state = LOGGED_IN;
                utils.storeLoginState(true, sUserName, sPassword);
                try {
                    client.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                state = LOGGED_IN;
                han.removeCallbacks(null);
                try {
                    client.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                //finish();

            } else {
                state = VERIFICATION_FAILED;
                utils.storeLoginState(false, "", "");
                onLoginFailed();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_SIGNUP) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                // TODO: Implement successful signup logic here
                // By default we just finish the Activity and log them in automatically
                this.finish();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Disable going back to the MainActivity
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

    public void onLoginFailed() {
        // ApplicationLoader._toast("Login failed",LoginActivity.this);
        _toast(getString(R.string.log_in_failed), LoginActivity.this);
        _passwordText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        _phoneInputView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        _loginButton.setEnabled(false);

        // Enable Login after 5000 ms with editing the number
        loginAgain.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                _loginButton.setEnabled(_phoneInputView.isValid());
            }
        }, 5000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        //disconnect();
    }

    public void resetPass(View view) {
        // Start the Signup activity
        Prefs.putInt(getString(R.string.key_reset_pass), 1);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SignUpActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PAS_RESET);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to create a service only for MQTT task (connect,subscribeand publish tasks).  Bind your MQTT service to the activities and you will not need to handle these task in every activity.